# Reading json response in windows power shell

Tags: json, powershell

I am using power shell code as:

```
   $web_client = new-object system.net.webclient
    $build_info=web_client.DownloadString("http://<URL>")
    $suitevm_build_number=
    $suitevmCLN=
    $webapp_build=
    $stats_build=
```

Output in browser while hitting http:// is:

```
{"message":null,"changeset":"340718","branch":"main","product":"productname","buildNumber":"1775951","todaysDate":"28-4-2014"}
```

What should I write the power shell code to get:

```
  $suitevm_build_number=
    $suitevmCLN=
    $webapp_build=
    $stats_build=
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your question is very unclear. If you have Powershell 3 or later, you can use `ConvertFrom-JSON` to convert the JSON response to an object.

```
$build_info=$web_client.DownloadString("http://<URL>") | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Ex of output:

```
$build_info

message     : 
changeset   : 340718
branch      : main
product     : productname
buildNumber : 1775951
todaysDate  : 28-4-2014
```

With PS 3+ you could also replace the WebClient with `Invoke-RestMethod` as shown by @RickH.

```
$build_info = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://<URL>"
```

Comment: Similarly PowerShell 3 or 4 includes [Invoke-RestMethod](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/hh849971.aspx) which will parse a JSON response to a PSObject in one step: `$build_info=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://<URL>'`

Comment: @Forde F And how to get these information from $build_info?

Comment: I have no idea what information should go where. But you assign values like `$stats_build = $build_info.changeset`...